# Как правильно фиксить баги?

Tags: git

При разработке часто приходится фиксить баги в проекте.
Я делаю это следующим образом:

создаю ветку `bugfix/*` от мастера, после фикса бага, делаю `git push origin HEAD`, далее в guthub создаю pull-request и происходит слияние с мастером. 
После чего, снова переключаюсь на мастер - `git checkout -`, и пишу `git pull origin master` чтобы у меня появились изменения.

Правильно ли так делать? Или есть другие способы ? 
Может вместо `git pull` надо merge локально?

Comment: почитайте про git-flow https://habr.com/ru/post/106912/

Comment: @Lexx918, спасибо, читал, необособленно сложная модель. 
предпочитаю github-flow

Comment: @22222222224 github-flow подразумевает деплой в прод из ветки до мержа ее с мастером, так что скорее всего у вас не он :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну можно всё и из командной строки делать

```
$ git pull
$ git checkout -b task_branch
...
$ git add path/to/file0
$ git rm path/to/file1
$ git mv path/to/file2 path/to/file3
...
$ git commit -am 'Changes'
$ git pull
$ git push
$ git checkout master
$ git merge task_branch
$ git push
```

Comment: Получается мы будем делать push в мастер ?

и еще не понял, для чего после комита делаем git pull - если буквально несколько команд выше делали?

Comment: И можно ли перед merge посмотреть, что будет добавлено в файлы а что удалено ?

Comment: да, в мастер, так как `git checkout master`. Можно конечно и другую ветвь тут забрать.

Comment: Изменения можно посмотреть об `git status` и `git diff`

Comment: обычно используют `git merge  --no-ff task_branch` чтобы в истории обязательно остался факт мержа

Comment: "для чего после комита делаем git pull" - Смотрите.... Забираем исходники, работаем с ними часы (дни?), работа готова, её надо push. Но за это время в репозитории возможно появились изменения. Поэтому их надо сначала pull, смержить конфликты, если вдруг будут и только потом push